# AS3: XPath returns XMLNode instead of XMLList if single match?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, xmlnode, xmllist

AS3

I'm trying to dynamically load pictures based on XML file. The problem that Im stuck with is a function that is supposed to return found node from supplied identifier.
Like in the following code

```
function getStudyById(id:String):XMLNode{
    var xl:XMLList = xml.bacase.(@name==id); // xml is a global variable
    return xl.children()[0]; // xl[0] does not work either
    // return (xl.length()>0) ? xl[0] : null;
}
```

The XML goes like this:

```
<root>
    <bacase name="a" />
    <bacase name="b" />
</root>
```

Anticipating your questions, it all is done in the COMPLETE event of the xml loader, once the XML has been loaded.

Now the problem is that the XMLList appears to be empty, while xml is correctly populated and the identifier definitely matches one of the nodes.
When I duplicate the queried node, the list traces correctly as containing two nodes. So my guess is that, if there is only a single match, the XMLList does not get created, and the result contains data of XMLNode data type.

Anyone there to confirm this? If so, is there a way to ensure that the query always returns XMLList type?

Thanks
Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLNode` works only with the old `flash.xml.XMLDocument`. A single node would be of type `XML` if you use `XML` or `XMLList`.

This snipped works fine for me:

```
var xml:XML = <root>
        <bacase name="a" />
        <bacase name="b" />
    </root>;

var p:XMLList = xml.bacase.(@name == "a");

if (p.length() > 0) return XML(p[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, definitely, I used XMLNode as the return type, but within the function I was declaring a XMLList to hold the result of the XPath query. Well, your snippet DOES work, thank you, but I aim at defensive programming, and would like to first check if the query returns any result, before referring to its zeroth child. I find it quite confusing that XMLList is not created when the query finds a single item.

Comment: **XMLNode** is depricated in AS3 and for usage with XMLDocument. `trace(xml.bacase.(@name == "a").length());` returns **1** for me. Did you do a trace within your function or with the function result?

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. You should not use `XMLNode`.

Comment: Didn't know the XMLNode has been deprecated. OK, now that I converted it to XML, the code works perfect, thank you!